# When does Entity Framework load rows into memory?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I know that I can use `ToList()` in my Entity Framework queries, in which case all rows are loaded into memory. But, otherwise, when are those rows loaded?

If I have a query that returns many rows, how can I ensure they are not all loaded into memory? (Like a data reader.)

Does someone know where this information is documented more clearly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the [Buffering and streaming](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/performance/efficient-querying#buffering-and-streaming) topic.

> Buffering refers to loading all your query results into memory,
> whereas streaming means that EF hands the application a single result
> each time, never containing the entire resultset in memory. In
> principle, the memory requirements of a streaming query are fixed -
> they are the same whether the query returns 1 row or 1000; a buffering
> query, on the other hand, requires more memory the more rows are
> returned. For queries that result large resultsets, this can be an important performance factor.
>
> Whether a query buffers or streams depends on how it is evaluated.

> Avoid using `ToList` or `ToArray` if you intend to use another LINQ operator on the result - this will needlessly buffer all results into memory. Use `AsEnumerable` instead.

You might also want to read the [Tracking, no-tracking and identity resolution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/performance/efficient-querying#tracking-no-tracking-and-identity-resolution) topic.

---

The below shows an example of a streaming approach.

```
foreach (var blog in context.Posts
    .AsNoTracking() // Or .AsNoTrackingWithIdentityResolution
    .Where(p => p.Title.StartsWith("A"))
    )
{
    // ...
}
```